# How can I learn to write this code more efficiently/creatively?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to go through the LeetCode problems and came across a problem where you had to turn a roman numeral into an integer. I thought my solution was good, it ran fast and worked properly and works with any roman numerals I plug in. I then looked at the discussion page and people were using dictionaries and other complex solutions. in comparison mine looks excessive. I came from an electronics background so I think that I sometimes think with a logic gate mindset when it comes to programming, how can I work on writing this solution more creatively?

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        i = 0
        number = 0
        while i < (len(s)):
            if s[i:i+2] == "IV":
                number = number + 4
                i += 2
            elif s[i:i+2] == "IX":
                number = number + 9
                i += 2
            elif s[i:i+2] == "XL":
                number = number + 40
                i += 2
            elif s[i:i+2] == "XC":
                number = number + 90
                i += 2
            elif s[i:i+2] == "CD":
                number = number + 400
                i += 2
            elif s[i:i+2] == "CM":
                number = number + 900
                i += 2
            elif s[i] == "I":
                number = number + 1
                i += 1
            elif s[i] == "V":
                number = number + 5
                i += 1
            elif s[i] == "X":
                number = number + 10
                i += 1
            elif s[i] == "L":
                number = number + 50
                i += 1
            elif s[i] == "C":
                number = number + 100
                i += 1
            elif s[i] == "D":
                number = number + 500
                i += 1
            elif s[i] == "M":
                number = number + 1000
                i += 1
        return number
```

I tried out a few different solutions, but did not come up with anything other than what I can describe as brute force programming.

Comment: This question _may_ be better suited for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as it represents complete, working code that you are looking to improve, as opposed to a problem/bug you are trying to solve.

Comment: Depends on your goal.  Were you trying to write code that was easy to read and understand, code that was easy to modify and enhance, code that was short so it could all be reasoned about at once, code that runs as fast as possible, or code that was fancier and showed off your programming prowess?  The code you create would look different for each of these goals.  It's like any other activity - you study other people's stuff, figure out how their stuff supports your goal, and practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic use for a Python dictionary: It would look something like this:

```py
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:

        romanIntMappings = {
            "IV": 4,
            "IX": 9,
            "XL": 40,
            "XC": 90,
            "CD": 400,
            "CM": 900,
            "I": 1,
            "V": 5,
            "X": 10,
            "C": 100,
            "D": 500,
            "M": 1000
        }
        i = 0
        number = 0
        while i < (len(s)):
            if s[i:i+2] in romanIntMappings:
                number = number + romanIntMappings[s[i:i+2]]
                i += 2
            elif s[i] in romanIntMappings:
                number = number + romanIntMappings[s[i]]
                i += 1
        return number
```

Comment: Thank you! that solution is much easier to read and I definitely understand it better than the others ones I've seen!

Comment: Great, then please accept the answer.